# Run access macro using task scheduler when computer is locked

Tags: windows, vba, ms-access-2010, bios

Can I run an access macro automatically and mail the output using Task scheduler automatically when my computer is in lock mode? It is running perfectly when my computer is logged in.

I need to run it on daily basis before my reporting time using scheduler. Is there is any way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

See the link below.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Follow all the steps.  That link has some good detail, but I think they miss a critical step at the end...this is your question.  So, also see this link below.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler

Pay attention to this step: 'run even when the user is not logged on'

You need to enter your Windows Password and save all your changes.  MAKE SURE YOU ENTER THE CORRECT PASSWORD.  I don't think the system prompts you if you enter the wrong password, so you think it may be set to run, but it won't actually trigger if the password is incorrect.

Good luck!!

Comment: Mark the answer as helpful. Thanks.